# Why do we need to inflate components of fragment while using it in an activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Why do we need to inflate components of fragment while using it in an activity?

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_section_fragment, container, false);
  }
```

Comment: If you want to show it, you have to inflate it ?!

Comment: Because `Fragment` is an independent part of the UI and can be used in many places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not inflating a fragment in the code snippet shown in your question. You are inflating the contents of the fragment.

Most fragments exist to manage some piece of user interface. `onCreateView()` is where you return that piece of user interface. Whether you inflate a layout resource or use Java constructors and methods to create the user interface programmatically is up to you.

Notable exceptions:

- Fragments where you inherit the piece of user interface (e.g., `ListFragment`)
- Fragments where you are not managing a piece of user interface (e.g., a model fragment)

Comment: Hi. Why is `ListFragment` an exception? So far, I've always inflated them into a `View` and then return that `View` in `onCreateView`. Would this be unnecessary? Thanks.

Comment: @CodingChap: Sorry, I meant that with a subclass `ListFragment`, you usually do not need `onCreateView()`, because you are inheriting an `onCreateView()` from `ListFragment` itself. Note that `ListFragment` has been obsolete for a few years now -- new construction in 2021 should lean towards a regular `Fragment` that uses a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the help. I'll use a Fragment and RecyclerView from now on.